# Button action doesn't respond when switched viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c

I have an app where the viewcontroller is switched if a button is pressed. I switch like this:

```
NewViewController *nv = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
[nv NewButtonTapped:self];
[self.view addSubview:nv.view];
```

Then in my NewViewController.m:

```
- (void)NewButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748)];
backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cubePage.png"];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];

button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(964, 100, 60, 150);
button.enabled = YES;
button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[button setTitle:@"D" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"Tapped");
}
```

All images and buttons are loaded and appears fine in the new viewcontroller but the button action `buttonTapped:` doesn't respond when I'm tapping the button. This code works fine in the first viewcontroller.
What's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure there are no views blocking the touches?

Comment: yes I am I have also tried to bring button to front